# Hosting Craft Site on Github Pages with Paid Domain

Tags: hosting

I'm planning to move from an outside free hosting site to [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) free hosting, my site is a small portfolio, but I make changes every now and then so I want to take advantage to have my changes live right when I push to my repository, not having to copy those files to my hosting server and etc. Also I currently have a paid domain, the process would be, host on Github Pages, and redirect to custom domain, in this case I use Hostinger.

If possible:

1. I currently have on my Repo the `templates` folder, and my the `public_html` folder, do I need to include the whole `craft` folder and structure?

Please any step by step procedure would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, sorry, just found out that Github Pages only works with static content (No PHP, No database).

Closing.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudways support Git Deployment. Using this you could have your site on Git and make continuous pushes from anywhere and pull it through Cloudways Control panel. For more information about this you could visit [here](https://support.cloudways.com/using-git-for-deployment/)